# Does $X$ have countable network if it has countable extent?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ have a $\sigma$-discrete network and have countable extent.

> **Does $X$ have countable network?**

A family $\mathcal N$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is a network for $X$ if for every point $x\in X$ and any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there exists an $M \in \mathcal N$ such that $x\in M \subset U$.

**A network is like a base, except that its members need not be open sets.**

Another question:

> **How could we see that every Moore space has a $\sigma$-discrete network?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{N}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathscr{N}_n$ be a $\sigma$-discrete network for $X$, where each $\mathscr{N}_n$ is discrete. Fix $n\in\omega$, and for each $N\in\mathscr{N}_n$ fix $x_N\in N$. Then $\{x_N:N\in\mathscr{N}\}$ is a closed, discrete subset of $X$, so it’s countable (since $X$ has countable extent), and therefore $\mathscr{N}_n$ is countable. It follows immediately that $\mathscr{N}$ is countable.

I’ll have to come back to the other question later.

Comment: @Brain: How could I see that $\{x_N: N\in \mathcal N\}$ is closed, discrete?

Comment: @Paul: $\bigcup\mathscr{N}_n$ is closed, as is $\bigcup(\mathscr{N}_n\setminus\{N\})$ for each $N\in\mathscr{N}_n$, so each point of $X$ has an open nbhd containing at most one $x_ N$.

Comment: What is nbhd of $x$ for each $x\in X$ witnesses that the set is closed discrete?

Comment: @Paul: Let $D_n=\{x_N:N\in\mathscr{N}_n\}$, and let $x\in X$. $\mathscr{N}_n$ is discrete, so $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ that intersects at most one $N\in\mathscr{N}_n$. Thus, $U$ contains at most one $x_N\in D_n$, and $D_n$ is closed and discrete.

Answer (score 2):

> **How could we see that every Moore space has a $\sigma$-discrete network?**

See [Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology](http://webfile.ru/6475714), Theorem 4.5 (p.447 of the book = p.436 of the file).